# can i cord Jquery datatables plugin data load by when each tab click

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

I would like to use DataTables to represent content of a huge table with about 1000,000 records.
Standard paging functionality is great and that is exactly what I need. Performance in my project is a critical condition.
User should be able to browse pages of the grid with minimal delay.

when user came to the page the 1000,000 records are loaded each time.it becames lot of time and use more data useage for load web page. I want to know can i load data when click on page number in jquery. I think it can reduce my data usage and speed of the page load... Please give me answer or onother way to do this.(when have 200 rows in datatables,the chrome developer options shows it retreives 3mb to load web page.I want to reduce that data usage using datatables features).I use Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this using server-side processing in DataTables. With server-side processing enabled, all paging, searching, ordering actions that DataTables performs are handed off to a server

Please go to the link below for more details.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Can I add server side processing without write ajax cord